# Enabling external access in windows azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am hosting web application in azure active directory.

I want to enable  an option called as **“External Access”** after clicking on the applications button.

Now, the issue is when I click on **“Add app” ,** I am not getting the option to select “Single sign on,read directory data”( I have added the screen shot below) , so eventually the “External Access” is not getting enabled in the applications tab.

Any solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Guess currently this option is renamed to Application is MultiTenant and you have to set this option for external access in the respective application's configure section.

Answer (score 1):

"External access" means that it is a multi-tenant application, where you expect to have more than one organization (or at least more than one directory) consuming the application. As @Bamura mentions, this was renamed in the Azure portal to "application is multi-tenant".

"Single sign-on", "read-only", etc. are permissions that an application has to a resource. One of these resources is Azure AD itself (via the Graph API), but it isn't the only one. For example, you can have one application representing a web API, and another application representing native client apps that access the web API.

You can control which permissions an app has under the "Permissions to other applications" section at the bottom of the 'Configure' screen. You'll notice the default is single sign-on delegated permission (i.e. as a user).